# how to verify credentials on a tizen wgt project

Tags: certificate, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I feel I have properly signed a Tizen for wearable .wgt file.

Is there a way to 'dump' the info for a .wgt to have it display security credentials (cert info), etc, to verify the .wgt has been signed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the command line interface, you can pass in the argument to log the signing process as the following.

```
cd .buildResult/ // you need to be where you have your build
web-signing -l info -p your_profile_name:path_to_your_profile
```

(you can replace "info" with the following: error, warning, info, debug, or trace)

for more details, search for command line interface in the IDE help content.